Unable to properly update activity_manager settings
I have a script running under Termux, which keeps getting killed by the activity manager after a while, complaining that it exceeded the CPU usage limits.
The OS is LineageOS 22 (Android 15), running on a Xiaomi Mi 9 SE
I did some searches, and it seems that there are 4 variables that control the killing: private static final String KEY_POWER_CHECK_MAX_CPU_1 = "power_check_max_cpu_1";
(cpu 1 to 4)
Those variables can be updated as such:
             sudo device_config put activity_manager power_check_max_cpu_1 1000 

After doing so, I can check to see if they are updated with   sudo device_config get activity_manager power_check_max_cpu_1
They are updated properly. However, If I do:
sudo dumpsys activity|grep -i power_check_max_cpu_1
it shows the old (default value). Rebooting doesn't help.
Any ideas?

Ok, it seems that for some reason setting those constants must be done 'the old way', using sudo settings put global activity_manager_constants power_check_max_cpu_1=256
